# Can I compose a hibernate Entity?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a project that I've recently inherited that has 2 tables that share a lot of common fields. I'm new to hibernate and want to know if I can use composition to generate the table instead of inheritance? B and D are basically the same class with a different table name.

Current Hierarchy is

- B extends A extends BaseClass
- D extends C extends BaseClass

My problem at the moment is that a lot of other classes extend BaseClass which don't have the shared fields and the 2 child classes don't share a common parent so I cannot add another level into the Hierarchy and use @MappedSuperclass.

Because of this I'd like to know if I can group my common fields into a single class and compose my child classes with this new class somehow?

Apologies for the cryptic names but as always; confidentiality...

edit - found something simmilar with @Embeddable https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/domain/embeddables.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the JPA interface to Hibernate, you can use `@Embedded` and  `@Embeddable`, to get more or less what you want. Be aware that the change will not be transparent: where you had:

```
@Entity
public class B extends A {
    @Basic
    private int foo;
    ...
}
```

that you referenced in JPQL by using `b.foo`, you will have:

```
@Embeddable
public classs Common {
    @Basic 
    private int foo;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class B extends A {
    @Embedded
    private Common common;
    ...
}
```

which you will have to reference in JPQL using `b.common.foo`.

Read more about embeddable entities here:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Embeddables

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially use @Embedded and embed the same object for both B and D, perhaps something like:

```
@Embeddable
public class CommonFieldObject {
  @Column(name="COMFIELD1")
  private String commonField1;

  @Column(name="COMFIELD2")
  private String commonField2;

  ...
}



@Table
public class C extends A {
  @Embedded
  @AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="commonField1", column=@Column(name="CFO_COMFIELD1")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="commonField2", column=@Column(name="CFO_COMFIELD2"))
  })
  private CommonFieldObject commonFieldObj; //CFO_ prefix for this reference - in case we have a second field referencing a CommonFieldObject - use a different prefix..

  ...
}
```

You should then get the columns CFO_COMFIELD1 and CFO_COMFIELD2 in your table and you can recycle the CommonFieldObject for class D.